# Electron child process sudo password prompt doesn't pipe to stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, electron

In my electron app I am trying to run a bash script that executes a sudo command.  Though I'm able to execute the script as sudo without issue, this isn't an option because the script needs to execute non privileged things things first.

```
const { spawn } = require('child-process-promise');    
var promise = spawn('bash', ['/Users/me/Desktop/test.sh']);

var childProcess = promise.childProcess;
childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('[spawn] stdout: ', data.toString());
});
childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('[spawn] stderr: ', data.toString());
});

promise.then(function () {
        console.log('[spawn] done!');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error('[spawn] ERROR: ', err);
    });
```

test.sh

```
echo 'test 1'
sudo echo 'test 2'
sudo -k
```

Running this will generate:

*[spawn] stdout:  test 1*

In my electron app's console as intended. However, the prompt for:

*Password:*

appears in the electron process terminal shell.

Is there a way to have this password prompt sent the the electron browser instead of the main terminal?

Comment: In your electron code watch for stdout data equating to "Pasword:" and then artificially surface the prompt in your app and feed the user input back into stdin? Just "proxy" the password prompting through the electron code.

Comment: @AlienHoboken how would you suggest watching for and surfacing messages that appear in the stdout shell?

Comment: In an attempt to capture the stdout of the main window I've tried something like this `remote.process.stdout.on('data', function (data) { console.log('[main] stdout: ', data.toString()); });` however nothing from that handler is ever output.